# Find the side of the square inside the regular pentagon

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, polygons, slope

In the given figure, there is a square $EFGH$ of side $x$ units inside a regular pentagon . Note that $E$ is the common vertex of square and pentagon. Find $x$.

[image]

My try:

We know that equation of $AB$ is $$y-0=-\cot(36^{\circ})(x-1)$$

For some $\lambda \in R$, the coordinates of $H$ is:
$$H(\lambda, (1-\lambda)\cot(36^{\circ}))$$

Now if we get $\lambda$, we can find $EH$.

But any clue how to find $\lambda$

Also the coordinates of $E$ is: $(\cos(288^{\circ}),\sin(288^{\circ}))$

Comment: It seems to me that the arithmetic might be easier if you put point $E$ at $(1, 0)$, because then point $H$ will be on the $y$-axis.  Try drawing the diagram that way and see if it looks any simpler.

Comment: Can I know the source of the question,please?

Comment: @MJD How do you know $H$ will be on Y-axis

Comment: I was mistaken.

Comment: Why did you think the posted answer was wrong? I see it is now deleted.

Comment: Yes because there is a contradiction when we apply sine rule in two triangles, because the solver assumed symmetry.

Comment: That's what i am telling, if we assume symmetry square is not possible.

Comment: oh yeah, i wrongly kept that, i am editing it

Comment: @MathLover, yes but symmetry will not give a square in my case where a vertex is common to square and pentagon

Comment: No such square exists. $DF=AH$ is necessary for $EF=EH$, but if constructed as such, $G$ is not on $BC$.

Comment: @Umeshshankar yes I agree on that. Had not read through it closely.

Comment: @Umeshshankar but your diagram shows that one of the vertices of the pentagon and square coincide

Comment: That was the reason I assumed the given answer was correct but looking closely, it does not work. That would mean the vertices cannot coincide.

Comment: Please answer to the question of @IITM : what is the origin of this problem ? Are you sure it has a solution ?

Comment: It is easy to show that there is NO such square if a vertex coincide with a pentagon vertex.

Comment: Please give the source of the problem. If this is an original question that appeared in some context, please give the source of the related context. Some "similar" issues appear here: (1) http://ken.duisenberg.com/potw/archive/arch98/981113sol.html (2) https://boredofstudies.org/threads/largest-square.253023/ (3) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JsN0zH_mdM ... In these links, the more or less poor quality of the presentation is of no benefit for the reader. On this site, there is a good tendency to get a good quality of the questions and answers. So *please* give the source.

Comment: Many people downvote anonymously, which I hate. I downvote in an open manner this old question because you are not fair with this site : you resist to give any mention of the source of this strange problem. I will upvote it when you have answered our query.

Answer (score 3):

This problem has no solution ! It is said more or less in different comments, that I try to put together here in order to close this question.

Indeed, if we attempt to build such a square with side $x$, due to the symmetry of the figure with respect to $EI$ (where $I$ denotes the midpoint of $BC$), the circle with center $E$ and radius $x$ would intersect $AB$ and $CD$ in $F$ and $H$ in such a way that $AH=DF$. Therefore the solution square would have its fourth vertex $G$ in $I$ for this symmetry reason.

But no square is possible in such a symmetrical configuration.

Here is a short proof: Let us assume that such a square with side $x$ exists, with $G=I$ the midpoint of $BC$. Let us denote by $y$ the side of the pentagon.

Knowing that the angles of the pentagon are $\frac15 540= 108°$, by angle chasing, $\angle DEF=9° \implies \angle DFE= 63° \implies \angle CFG=27°$.

As a consequence, applying sine law

- to triangle $DEF$: $\dfrac{y}{x}= \dfrac{\sin 63°}{\sin 108°}$
- to triangle $CFG$: $\dfrac{y/2}{x}= \dfrac{\sin 27°}{\sin 108°}$

It would mean that

$$\sin 63°=2 \times \sin 27°\tag{3}$$

which is false (I am indebted to @Intelligenci Pauca for having spotted an error of mine in this reasoning).

In fact, the LHS and RHS of (3) differ by $0.017$ which is not very important...

Comment: But side $CG$ is not $x/2$.

Comment: I'd rather suggest: $${1\over\sin63°}={x\over\sin108°}={1/2\over\sin27°},$$ that is $\sin63°=2\sin27°=2\cos63°$, which is false.

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca. My bad ! I correct it following your suggestion... Thanks a lot...

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca.  You are too modest. "Intelligenti multa" should be more adapted...

Comment: It is not a matter of being humble: I think good maths should be conveyed in a minimum of words. Just as the ancient masters did.